# How to joint 3 table where one table map id from the two other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display on a page every file linked to the user logged in, displaying the relevant info about the file, the user and who the file is about.

Here are the tables :

```
staff     users     map_file_users   files       category
id        id        id               id          id
pwd       name      file_id -------> ...         name
user_id-> ...  <--- user_id          category -->...
```

To do that I used this code that shows every file published by the user logged in retrieving the column that I need:

```sql
SELECT info_client.name        AS client_name,
       info_client.surname     AS client_surname,
       info_staff.surname      AS staff_surname,
       info_staff.name         AS staff_surname,
       files.creation_date     AS file_creation_date,
       files.modification_date AS file_modification_date,
       files.size              AS file_size,
       files.type              AS file_type,
       category.name           AS file_category
FROM files
         INNER JOIN clients client      ON files.about_client = client.id
         INNER JOIN users info_client   ON info_client.id = client.user_id
         INNER JOIN staff staff         ON files.published_by = staff.user_id
         INNER JOIN users info_staff    ON info_staff.id = staff.user_id
         INNER JOIN categories category ON files.category = category.id
WHERE files.published_by = :id;
```

I do not take advantages of the table "map_file_staff" to display all file linked to user logged in. This "map_file_staff" table would also allow me easily to allow / disallow someone from accessing the file by simple inserting the file id and user id into it.

Hope it's clear !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```sql
select staff.surname           as staff_surname,
       staff.name              as staff_name,
       files.title             as file_title,
       files.creation_date     as file_creation_date,
       files.modification_date as file_modification_date,
       files.size              as file_size,
       files.type              as file_type,
       category.name           as file_category,
       client.name             as client_name,
       client.surname           as client_surname

from map_file_user
         INNER JOIN users as staff on staff.id = map_file_user.user_id
         INNER JOIN files on files.id = map_file_user.file_id
         INNER JOIN categories category on files.category = category.id
         INNER JOIN clients c on files.about_client = c.id
         INNER JOIN users as client on client.id = c.id
WHERE map_file_user.user_id = 2;
```